# exploding multiple columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Need to explode the data on multiple columns in pandas
input dataframe:

```
df
SRCA    SRCB  SRC_CNTA  SRC_CNTB
A,B     G,H     1           1
E,C,D   Z,Y,K   2           2
```

code that is used for this is:
df.set_index(['SRC_CNTA','SRC_CNTB']).apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index()
This will exclude the index columns and to apply explode on remaining columns.

Expected output:

```
SRCA    SRCB  SRC_CNTA  SRC_CNTB  SRCA_EXP  SRCB_EXP
A,B     G,H     1           1       A       G   
A,B     G,H     1           1       B       H
E,C,D   Z,Y,K   2           2       E       Z
E,C,D   Z,Y,K   2           2       C       Y
E,C,D   Z,Y,K   2           2       D       K
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use apply (the vectorized version, so it's not slow) to `split` and `explode` both columns. Then we `join` back on index:

```
expl = df[["SRCA", "SRCB"]].apply(lambda col: col.str.split(",").explode()).add_suffix("_EXP")
df = df.join(expl).reset_index(drop=True)
```

```
    SRCA   SRCB  SRC_CNTA  SRC_CNTB SRCA_EXP SRCB_EXP
0    A,B    G,H         1         1        A        G
1    A,B    G,H         1         1        B        H
2  E,C,D  Z,Y,K         2         2        E        Z
3  E,C,D  Z,Y,K         2         2        C        Y
4  E,C,D  Z,Y,K         2         2        D        K
```